# Having issue with jQuery animate()

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-animate

Here is my html doc. I'm trying to work my one header to another position using jQuery `animate()` and for some reason I can't get it to fire. The `fadeOut` and `fadeIn` work so I know that my JavaScript href is working.  Also, it doesn't have to do with not declaring the document type.

```
 <html>
 <head>
 <title>We Hate Treyarch - Let your opinions mean something </title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
 <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript">
 $(function(){
 $(window).load(function(){
 $("#underhead").animate
 ({top:600px;left:600px;},2000);
 $("#underhead").animate
 ({top:170px;left:165px;},5000);
 });
 });
 </script>
 </head>

<body>

<div id="tophead"></div>
<div id="sechead"> </div>

<div id="header">
 <h1 id="hye">We <span class="kame"><b>hate</b></span> treyarch</h1>
 </div>
 <div id="underhead">and so do you...</div>
 </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: Additionally, you would probably benefit from learning to use the Error Console, which is available in all major browsers. Both of them trigger an error when processing your code. **In Chrome:** http://i.stack.imgur.com/tuSCr.png **In Firefox:** http://i.stack.imgur.com/IerKM.png *(sorry for not embedding the images, StackOverflow prevents new users from doing so)*

Answer (score 4):

A javascript object is not defined like this:

```
{top:600px;left:600px;}
```

It's this:

```
{top:"600px", left:"600px"}
```

This must be javascript syntax, not CSS syntax.

This should have been described for you in the javascript error console or the console window in whatever js debugger you use as it's a javascript syntax error.

Also, there no reason to use both:

```
$(function(){
```

with this inside of it:

```
$(window).load(function(){
```

Use one or the other.  I'd suggest just the jQuery version unless you have to wait for images to finish loading in which case only use the window.load version.

This code works:

```
 $(function(){
     $("#underhead").animate({top: "600px", left: "600px"}, 2000);
     $("#underhead").animate({top: "170px", left: "165px"}, 5000);
 });
```

and you can see it in action here: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/V23rW/.

Comment: I changed everything up to what you said but still nothing..I removed the first function and left $(window).load(function(){ 
 plus changed to proper javascript syntax but nothing is working..I am using IE9 does it not work in that or how do i go about finding out my error..Im rather a beginner tahnks

Comment: Oh man thanks that actually did work i didnt do the second part!

Comment: I'm not sure what to tell you.  When I distill the code down to a simple jsFiddle here (http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/V23rW/), it works fine in IE9 so there's something wrong in the part that you're not showing us.  Is `#underhead` styled as `position: absolute`?  If it isn't, then animating top and left won't do anything.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the correct animate syntax, yours is wrong.

```
$('#id').click(function() {
  $('.class').animate({
    opacity: 0.25,
  }, 5000, function() {
  });
});
```

Comment: Could you give me an example of that?